# Sencha Touch android keypad hiding textarea

Tags: android, keyboard, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

[image]
`

```
constructor: function() {
          this.adjustHeight = Ext.Function.createBuffered(function(textarea) {
            var textAreaEl = textarea.getComponent().input;

            if (textAreaEl) {
              textAreaEl.dom.style.height = 'auto'; 
              var iNewHeight = textAreaEl.dom.scrollHeight;
              if (iNewHeight > 0) {
                textAreaEl.dom.style.height = textAreaEl.dom.scrollHeight + "px";
              }
            }
          },200,this);

          this.callParent(arguments);
        }
```

I want the `textarea` focused with full content `visible` . But text area hiding with keypad

Comment: You could try to use list.getScrollable().getScroller().scrollTo(Element) if there are enough elements following.

Comment: I have try that but it will produce jumping effect @ProtoBassi

Comment: Did you try on before focus

Comment: if (iNewHeight > 0) {
     textAreaEl.dom.style.height = textAreaEl.dom.scrollHeight + "px";
    this.getParent().getParent().getScrollable().getScroller().scrollTo(0, iNewHeight);                                                                                                                      }

Comment: previously i try like this

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the onBeforeFocus event with scrolling:

```
scrollableView.scrollTo(textfield.element.getXY()[0],textfield.element.getXY()[1]);
```

And now you might want to do this to all textfields and textareafields, so that the user gets the same on all items.

Make sure, that the effect is either earlier than the keypad animation or delay it with about 175ms.

```
Ext.defer(function() {###your code goes here###}, 175, this);
```